# Is reflected XSS impossible, when HTML meta-characters, e.g., < and >, are encoded, and the result output in HTML context?

Tags: xss, html, encoding

> Is reflected XSS impossible, when HTML meta-characters, e.g., < and >, are encoded, and the result output in HTML context?

I have a website that displays the URL path directly in HTML context, i.e.,

`www.mysite.com/helloworld` results in `helloworld` being displayed between `<body>` tags.

However, some meta-characters, e.g., `<` and `>`, are HTML escaped.

In this case, is it possible to perform a reflected XSS attack, like some esoteric UTF encoding attack etc.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reflected XSS script passing through URL how to make it work and what are the preconditions for it to work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/67790/reflected-xss-script-passing-through-url-how-to-make-it-work-and-what-are-the-pr)

Answer (score 6):

This depends on the context. I am assuming you're using `htmlentities()` function, which would be generally safe. It does more or less the exact same thing as `htmlspecialchars()` does.

Both of which secure against general XSS, and prevent event-based XSS when the sanitized parameter is injected into a HTML tag.

They both do not prevent `javascript:` attacks, which can happen if injecting the parameter value into a link, iframe, or other similar tag. If injecting a `src` or `href` from any of them tags, I would recommend first removing any whitespace from the parameter, and then checking for both `javascript:` and `data:`.

`javascript:alert(0)` will give you an alert when injected into a link or iframe.
`data:text/javascript:alert(0)` will do the same.
`data:text/html:<script>alert(0);</script>` does the same thing too, and bypasses `strip_tags`.

The reason for first removing whitespace, is to prevent an attacker dropping a line break/CRLF character in the middle of their payload, so PHP reads it as not being `javascript:` or `data:` when blocking the payload, but it will still execute as javascript will ignore it.

I hope that explains what type of attacks are possible, it's very easy to claim that `htmlentities()` and `htmlspecialchars()` are a one-fits-all solution to the problem, but depending on the situation, that can be extremely dangerous advice.

Comment: Don't try to sanitize. Pseudo-protocol `javascript:` is not always required. Simply apply OWASP's rules: no plain custom data in `src` or `href` attribute (only insert dynamic data here if the complete origin is constant). See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.230_-_Never_Insert_Untrusted_Data_Except_in_Allowed_Locations

Comment: Yes, I meant to add a colon. Thanks for the correction. And although it'd be great if everyone followed OWASP's rules, it is important to note that these attacks exist. My above sanitized example should be impossible to bypass. Let me know if you find a non-whitespace character to bypass.

Comment: That would still allow [ssh:](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml) protocol or any other (harmful) protocol. Besides, I wonder what you would like to do if you get the `javascript:` or `data:` matching (since it's not in the answer)... And if you've also [include `U+000C` in the whitespace list to remove](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#ascii-whitespace) [Note: that might be better suited for chat] And you cannot tell if new protocol will appear in the next years that would be injectable as `javascript:` is

Comment: You raise some good points. On a personal level, I would never trade security for functionality, but a lot of developers would rather place raw input into the value of a link or iframe. A solution I would use to sanitize it would be ``preg_replace("/\s+/", "", htmlentities($input));`` which would encode the user's input using the ``htmlentities()`` function as suggested by OP, and then replace all whitespace. The result of this should be easily checked for ``javascript:`` and ``data:`` as there are no whitespace characters in there.

Comment: You then block legitimate URLs with whitespaces, and still allow some harmful ones like [`blob:`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#scheme-fetch)

Comment: ``blob:`` is a good point. No legitimate URL would have the whitespaces which are being stripped. If they do, it's not blocking them, only stripping them, which shouldn't usually be an issue.

Comment: I know this was posted a while ago, but it should be worth mentioning that ``blob:`` and ``data:`` both execute outside of context; without access to any cookies. This isn't the same for ``javascript:``. I'd be interested to see a ``blob:`` payload if you have one?

Answer (score 0):

If quotes are not escaped and the text is placed inside of a quoted html attribute, then a value that sets a javascript-bearing attribute like `" onmouseover="alert(0)` may work.

Comment: No, HTML entities will be read as an actual value, and be given no significant authority. I tested your example and it does not work in my case. I don't see this working but maybe it is browser specific or something?

Comment: If the server generated some html by doing `'<div title="' + yourValue + '">'`, then injecting the value `" onmouseover="alert(0)` will result in the html `<div title="" onmouseover="alert(0)">`, which will trigger some javascript when the user hovers over the element.

Comment: There are better alternatives for event-based payloads (such as onload where possible, or even some onfocus combined with autofocus will automatically execute the payload too). Still, I don't believe PHP would allow this when the ``htmlentities()`` function is being used.

Comment: The quotes are a meta HTML character that would have been encoded as shown in [HTML living spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#escapingString)

Comment: I agree that any good standard html encoding function will encode quotes, but OP doesn't know that the site is using such a function if they don't test for it. I've seen multiple sites in the wild which specifically encoded `<` and `>` but not quotes.